# combining query objects or get union of them

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a few custom find queries and I would like to combine them.

For example `findOwnedBy` method returns a query object where a particular customer is owned by a user. `findInGroups` methods return an other query object where the customer belons to the given group.

I would need to combine these to queries.

I tried the following code

```
public function findAccessibleBy(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $owned = $this->findOwnedBy($query, $options);
    $accessViaGroups = $this->findInGroups($query, $options);
}
```

If I have only the first find I get the correct query in `$owned`. If I add the second one, than `$owned` will be empty.

I tried chaning them together and I tried make union of them, but none of these worked.

I am sure I am missing something simple but I do not know what.

Comment: What was the problem when attempting an `union()` ?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo One of the called methods use `contain`, so I can not make an union, as these two has different number of selected fields. That is why I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343250/remove-fields-from-select-generated-by-matching Than I realized, that `$query` is different before `$owned`'s line, and right after that. I run out of ideas how to do this. :(