# remove fields from select generated by matching

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I have two custom find methods and I would like to make an union of them.

```
public function findInGroup(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
      ->matching(
          'Groups',
          function ($q) {
                  return $q->where(['Groups.id' => 1]);
              }
      );
}

public function findAsUser(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
      ->matching(
          'Users',
          function ($q) {
                  return $q->where(['Users.id' => 1]);
              }
      );
}
```

The two methods generates different `select` list, because of the `matching` call. So I can not make union of them...

I do not need `Groups__id`, etc fields to be selected.

Is there any way to tell to `matching` that it should not add the matching data fields to the created select field list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options"

### Select all the fields from the main query

That will make the query builder omit the fields from associations:

```
$query
    ->find('iGroup', $options)
    ->find('asUser', $options)
    ->select($table->schema()->columns());
```

By specifically selecting the columns you need, you will leave out the columns form associations that can be joined, i.e. the columns from matching.

### Use CakePHP 3.1

CakePHP 3.1 introduces a new function called `innerJoinWith()`, it does exactly the same as `matching()` but it will not select any columns from the association:

```
public function findInGroup(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
      ->innerJoinWith(
          'Groups',
          function ($q) {
                  return $q->where(['Groups.id' => 1]);
              }
      );
}

public function findAsUser(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
      ->innerJoinWith(
          'Users',
          function ($q) {
                  return $q->where(['Users.id' => 1]);
              }
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I has to tweak a little bit the first solution, but now it seems to work. And I will change to the other solution as 3.1 will be out. :)